# Getting pop up on every android mobile that entered into a particular location which I specified

Tags: javascript, java, html

I'm working on a project which require a pop up notification on every mobile phone which entered into a location that I specified., so please can anyone let me know, how can I do this?? Thank you in advance..

Comment: I really hope that's not possible! I certainly don't want just anybody to be able to pop up a message on my phone. Did you perhaps just want users of _your_ app to get a pop-up when they enter an area? If so, you should edit your question to be more clear.

Comment: Is it at least possible to give a pop up on selected mobile numbers when they entered a location that I specified??

Comment: Not unless they are running an app that lets you. Technically, it's possible: many places have government-run emergency measures organizations that (supposedly) feed emergency alerts to everybody within their jurisdiction. Those have been fraught with problems. You're simply not _supposed_ to have access to put things on my phone.